# Submitting form action using javascript codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have error for submitting form using javascript. the error said unknown column array. what is wrong with my array or maybe on my javascript.

this is my sample code.

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="age">

    <input type="button"onClick="this.form.action='<?php echo site_url('core')?>/'+'add_name';this.form.submit();" value="new"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `echo site_url('core');` return ? Seems like it's returning an array

Comment: site_url is for localhost? or like base_url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKING WITHOUT JS**
Try this:

```
<?php
$frmAttrs  = array("id"=>"addFrm");
echo form_open('core/add_name', $frmAttrs);
?>
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="age">

<!-- <input type="button" onClick="this.form.action='<?php //echo site_url('core/')?>'+'add_name';this.form.submit();" value="new"/> -->
<input type="button" id="submitFrm" onClick="this.form.submit();" value="new" />
</form>
```